# How to use @property decorator correctly in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties, decorator, python-decorators

I have method annotated with `@property` in `athleteModel.py` script:

```
@property
def get_from_store():
    with open(athleteFilePath,'rb') as pickleFile:
        athleteMap = pickle.load(pickleFile)
    print('Loaded athleteMap ',athleteMap)
    return athleteMap
```

I use this method in another script:

```
from athleteModel import get_from_store

athletes = get_from_store
print(yate.u_list(athletes[athName].sortedTimes))
```

At last line (`print` method) I get exception:

```
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable 
      args = ("'function' object is not subscriptable",) 
      with_traceback = <built-in method with_traceback of TypeError object>
```

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: I thought python generates it instead of me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@property` only works on *methods*, not on functions.

`get_from_store` is not a method, it is a function. A `property` object act as a [descriptor object](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) and descriptors only work in the context of classes and instances.

In your case there is no need to make `get_from_store` a property, really. Remove the `@property` decorator and just use it like a function:

```
athletes = get_from_store()
```

You cannot otherwise make top-level functions act like attributes.

Comment: How do you differ function and method?

Comment: @VolodymyrLevytskyi: a method is a function bound to an instance.